# Prefix/suffix property of language containing only empty word

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-languages, formal-grammars

Does language $L ={\varepsilon}$, where $\varepsilon$ - empty word has suffix/prefix property?

The definition says that language has prefix/suffix property requires that there is no code word in the system that is a prefix (initial segment) of any other code word in the system.

So if we have this finite language with $\varepsilon$ this mean that, there arent any prefix/suffix of empty word so our language has or not prefix/suffix property?

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean $L=\{\varepsilon\}$, i.e. the language which contains only the empty word, as opposed to the empty language. Both the empty language and the language which contains only the empty word have the prefix/suffix property, since they satisfy the definion.

However, the prefix property is a property of a code, not a property of a language. A language can describe a code, but neither the empty language nor the language which contains only the empty word describe a code. So in the end it is irrelevant whether those languages have the prefix/suffix property.

**Edit** rici is right that Hopcroft&Ullman say that the LR(0) grammars define exactly the DCFL's having the prefix property. (They hasten to add that the prefix property is not a severe restriction.) So in this case it is good that the empty language and the language which contains only the empty word have the prefix property. Additionally, Berstel&Perrin allow the empty set as a code, so you can also dispute my other claim. But they agree that $\{\varepsilon\}$ has the prefix property, and is not a code:

> **Proposition 2.1.9** *Any prefix (suffix, bifix) set of words $X\neq \{\varepsilon\}$ is a code.*

Both Hopcroft&Ullman and Berstel&Perrin consider $\varepsilon$ to be a prefix/suffix of any word, but they require a proper prefix/suffix in the definition of the prefix/suffix property. (This is clearly the right thing to do, otherwise no set of words would have the prefix/suffix property.)

Comment: The "prefix property" is a property of a set of strings. Where the set comes from is more or less irrelevant to the definition; the set could be the set of codings, as you suggest, but it could just as well be the set of strings derived by a grammar. A language is nothing other than a set of strings. So it is perfectly reasonable to say that a language has the prefix property. You'll find such a definition in Hopcroft&Ullman, for example.

Comment: I couldn't find a clickable link for page 254 in Hopcroft&Ullman but here's an example from a different textbook: https://books.google.com.pe/books?id=bmlUBudVqoMC&pg=PA272&lpg=PA272&dq=context+free+language+%22prefix+property%22&source=bl&ots=MxfPzdqzbB&sig=ACfU3U3qN6tggezqrbIiyIiAC5q6fAAH-g&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiKyrb6g6HgAhWwxVkKHaBWC0g4ChDoATADegQIBxAB#v=onepage